# Stored procedure can re-use temp table but raw query cannot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Consider the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spTest
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO #Test FROM [orders] 
    SELECT * FROM #Test
    -- notice no cleanup of temp table 
END
```

In SSMS i can do this:

```
spTest
GO
spTest
GO
```

and I get two result sets

However, if I do this:

```
SELECT * INTO #Test FROM [orders]
SELECT * FROM #Test
GO

SELECT * INTO #Test FROM [orders]
SELECT * FROM #Test
GO
```

I get an error that the temp table already exists.

Why, within a stored procedure do I not have to clean up the temp table but in a raw query, I do?

The above queries are run in the same SSMS window and therfore the same connection

NB - I realise it is good practive to delete temp tables when finished with them

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857433/temporary-tables-in-stored-procedures might have the answer.   My thoughts, it's a 'per instance' thing, I think when you call the stored proc it sort of it makes its own instance so the temp tables each clean up, but your window (even with `go`) is the same instance.  I wonder though if you called the proc twice at the same time if they would bump into each other or deadlock? hmm!

Comment: @sniperd I've amended the question. They are all in the same SSMS window and therefore same connection

Comment: Related to temp tables in procs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51507785/why-does-updating-a-real-table-from-a-self-join-temp-table-is-not-working-but-wh/51507870#51507870

Comment: Temp tables in procs are auto cleaned up at the end of execution.

Comment: @dfunkdako. Thanks, I'd never have found that post based on the post title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you can create a #Temp table once within a scope. When you are calling your SP twice, the SP runs in separate scope and thus you are not getting error. But when you are doing the same operation twice in single scope, you will get that error.